# Read text from console C#

Tags: c#

I have a question that i could not find on the internet.
For i friend of mine i am making a application that wil work after a command. Pretty easy but here comes the tricky part. That command is given in a other console. So what i am trying to do is read the lines from the other console and that should trigger an action in mine to write to the other console.

Like i said i've tried to find something on the internet that can help me but i could not find anything.

Is this possible and if it is possible how can i accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The other console is an gameserver that is started with an batch file

I could trigger the gameserver from my own application, but it will take over the program so how can i make it that it triggers in my program and then read the lines from the program

Comment: Very unclear... what is this `other console` that you speak of?

Comment: So you are going to read off of some other process's STDIN? Interesting, but I doubt its possible, if for no other reason than this could *easily* be malicious (a keylogger for example).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the console part? I'm not entirely sure I understand the issue.

Comment: Can you control how the gameserver is started? Can you change it so that it is started through a program you control?

Comment: @AndersAbel Anders? Kentor?

Comment: I could trigger to start the gameserver from my console but than the server takes over and i probely cannot read the lines

Comment: Use Console.ReadLine. :) You may find this useful: [Understanding C#: Use System.Console to build text-mode games](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-text-mode-games.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to control the input of the gameserver, you should start the gameserver from your application, so that you get control over the standard input of the gameserver.

Then you read all the lines from standard input, and check them before writing them to the gameserver's standard input. That way you can also write extra lines to the gameserver's standard input.

Code from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/46c91711-755f-48fa-a4a8-92956082218f/howto-launch-process-and-write-to-its-stdin:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //required to redirect standart input/output

// redirects on your choice
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

startInfo.FileName = ...app path to execute...;
startInfo.Arguments = ...argumetns if required...;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

process.StandardInput.WriteLine(...write whatever you want...);
```

Comment: And how can i read the lines from the server

Comment: You won't have to read the lines from the server. You read all the lines in your program through `Console.ReadLine` and then you forward them to the gameserver through `process.StandardInput.WriteLine` that way you'll have the data before you forward it.